# post rating for an individual item in a list using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, sql-update

I’m having a heck of a time figuring out how to post a rating for an individual item in a list of items,

this code let’s me rate multiple items, but not single items:

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
    $doc_item_id = $_POST['item_id0'][$i];
    $doc_rating  = $_POST['document_rating'][$i];

    $it_rt = array(
        'item_id' => $doc_item_id,
        'rating'  => $doc_rating,
    );  
    $this->purchases_model->update_document($it_rt);
}
```

whereas this code let’s me rate only the first item (or last item depending on where i put the "break;"):

```
foreach($_POST['item_id0'] as $doc_item_id){  
    foreach($_POST['document_rating'] as $doc_rating){
    }
    break;
}
$it_rt = array(  
    'item_id' => $doc_item_id,
    'rating'  => $doc_rating,
);
$this->purchases_model->update_document($it_rt);
```

any thoughts on how to correct either of these such that the user could rate the individual item of their choosing would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: You can use a better html solution. Like having a radio button for each item and having all the buttons in the same group. then having only one rating field that gets directly mapped to the corresponding item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is supposed to choose the item to rate (instead of rating all items at the same time), you should allow him to do so (showing only one item, let him select one using radio buttons...), and then you should be able, by PHP side, to retrieve the index of the item to modify.

Finally, in order to modify only one item, your code should look like (PHP side, you will certainly have to update your HTML form as well)

```
$i = $_POST['item_index']; // Here I'm supposing that you have added radio buttons
                           // named 'item_index' to allow user to choose the item to rate

$doc_item_id = $_POST['item_id0'][$i];
$doc_rating = $_POST['document_rating'][$i] ;

$it_rt = array(  
      'item_id'=> $doc_item_id,
      'rating' => $doc_rating,
      );

$this->purchases_model->update_document($it_rt);
```

In fact it would be nearly your original code without the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks khez and frosty z, got rid of the foreach loops and fixed some part of the html and now it works!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Don't forget to upvote/accept answers if you found them useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the entire list just to limit the item you want, is kinda bad.

Here's an example on how to do it using some array functions:

```
$last=true; // false for first
if($last){
   $id=end($_POST['item_id0']);
}else{
   $id=reset($_POST['item_id0']);
}
// alternative: $id=($last)?end($_POST['item_id0']):reset($_POST['item_id0']);

// test id
if($id===false){
   // no item was supplied
}
if(!isset($_POST['document_rating'][$id])){
   // somehow, the item id doesn't have a matching document rating
}

// everything is okay!
$doc_item_id = $_POST['item_id0'][$id];
$doc_rating  = $_POST['document_rating'][$id];

$it_rt = array(
    'item_id' => $doc_item_id,
    'rating'  => $doc_rating,
);

$this->purchases_model->update_document($it_rt);
```